# Reclaiming Inactive YouTube Username?

Tags: youtube

This account has been inactive for 5 years, 3 comments since January 13, 2009. I've sent around 13 messages and no response.

Is there anyway that I'm able to either reclaim the username orrr have YouTube try and send a personal e-mail to the account?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do about it. Even if you somehow contact YouTube, they will just day, "We don't do that".

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "reclaim"?   Is it your account?   Why can't you just use the regular forgotten password routines?

Or if it's not yours - then what makes you think you have a right to it?